# Does the expression "Senate of yore," mean what the Senate has been doing for over the decade?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Reading [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/timing-everything-biden-says-politics-120721081.html) there is a line,

> Biden also recalled the **Senate of yore,** as he has done multiple times as president: “It used to be you had to stand there and talk and talk and talk and talk until you collapsed. And guess what, people got tired of talking.”

I thought first Biden recalled he has been the old decades member of Senate, since the word yore is defined by Merriam,

> time past and especially long past —usually used in the phrase of yore

But when I think like that, the following line

> as he has done multiple times as president:

will not make sense.

So,

**Does the expression "Senate of yore," mean what the Senate has been doing for over the decade?**

Thank you for your precious time.

Comment: I kinda doubt Biden himself used the word "yore" like that. Sure, he's ***old***, but the word "yore" itself is positively ***Victorian***. In context, I'd say it's a slightly facetious usage from the writer (who probably *didn't* intend to make Biden seem even older than he is, "by association" with outdated vocabulary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence says that Biden is recalling *what the Senate used to do*, and that he has talked about this many times since becoming president. You might rephrase this:

> On several occasions since Biden became president, he has recalled how the Senate was in the old days.